# Polynomial Code 22

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program to allow the user to input two polynomials with different degrees, I believe that my do while loop is incorrect and I cannot figure out how to let the user input the second polynomial.

```
    {
    int i, coef, x, deg;
    double total=0.0;

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Degree");
    deg=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter x");
    x=sc.nextInt();
    do
    {
    for (i=0; i<=deg; i++) 
       {
          System.out.println("Enter Coefficent for " +i);
         coef=sc.nextInt();
         total=total+coef*Math.pow(x,i);
     }

 }
       while ( deg != 0);
```

Comment: You never change `deg`'s value, so your loop is infinite

Comment: This is [tag:java], right? What do you think it has to do with writing compilers?

Comment: i just added compiler as a tag because it was asking for one... I figured out how to get the program to print two polynomials but now I am struggling with adding a menu of options for the user... any advice on how to structure this?

Comment: Can you specify the language in the tags please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this forum but i changed the language to java... I know that I need to write the menu itself and then use a switch statement or and if else statement... One of the options for the menu is to evaluate the first at a value of x specified by the user. How would I write this option?